why is the output of char* "stuff here"[int here] a char*?
in my code, there is a line char* chunktl[140]; which defines chunktl as an array of chars, later code fills in what those values are but that isnt relevant, there is another line int arrayloc = relx + 7 +(8-rely)*16; which defines arrayloc as an int, what the variables are does not matter, however, the error
error: passing argument 1 of ‘pixrender’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  206 |                                                 pixrender(chunktl[arrayloc]);
      |                                                           ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
      |                                                                  |
      |                                                                  char *
terraria.c:81:22: note: expected ‘char’ but argument is of type ‘char *’
   81 | char* pixrender(char a)
      |                 ~~~~~^



still shows up and suggests that chunktl[arrayloc] is a string?
I tried makng arrayloc into various types (unsigned int, long, etc) which did not fix it

which defines chunktl as an array of chars - it does not. It defines an array of pointers to char. OTOH, char blah[140]; is an array of chars

ohhh,thx, I get it now

char* chunktl[140]; creates an array of 140 pointers (char *).
chunktl[arrayloc] returns one of those pointers.
You pass one of these pointers to pixrender.
pixrender wants a char, not a pointer.
If you want an array of 140 char values, you want char chunktl[140];.

A traditional walkthrough. +1

is there a way to convert the pointer into the char its pointing to?

*p ___________
